# how to iterate a List that contains Map and get the key and value of that map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a `list` that contains a map on class type. I want to iterate that `list` and get the `key` and `values` of the inner map.

Here is the `List` :

```
quotationList =  quotationService.searchByIdList(accountId, Account.class);
```

It contains one index i.e at 0 index it contains a map. i need to get the key and values of that map.

My attempt:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quotationList.size(); i++) {
            Map myMap = (Map) quotationList.get(i);
            System.out.println("Data For Map" + i);
            for (Entry<String, Object> entrySet : ((Map<String, Object>) myMap).entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entrySet.getKey() + " , Value = " + entrySet.getValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<quotationList.size();i++)
        {
   Map myMap =  (Map) quotationList.get(i);
   System.out.println("Data For Map" + i);

   for (Entry<String, Object> entrySet : ((Map<String, Object>) myMap).entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entrySet.getKey() + " , Value = " + entrySet.getValue());
            }
        }

Getting Error in converitng object to map

Comment: Give the type of List when initialzing List , for eg: List<Map<String,String>> quotationList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>(); Then typecast it correctly back at quotationsList.get(i). Otherwise your logic seems correct :)

Comment: What is the declaration of `quotationList`, why do you need a `Map` cast ? What is wrong with you attempt ? Please provide a [mcve], showing the list declaration, example of data inserted in that list, ...

Comment: It gives me an class cast exception, com.mycaptionlabs.domain.user.Account cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: You have an `Account` instance in that `List`, not a `Map`. That's why it is important to give us every information. What is the `Map` you are hoping to get and print ? PS : Please [edit] the question with that information.

Comment: And what is the error and on which line ? Of course, using `List` == `List<Object>` is always a bad start. You should specify the type here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first item in the list:

```
Map<MyKey, MyValue> myMap = quotationList.get(0);
```

To get the values of the map:

```
myMap.entrySet();
```

Next step would be to loop that entrySet:

```
    for (Entry<MyKey, MyValue> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        MyKey key = entry.getKey();
        MyValue value = entry.getValue();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this similar approach. But not working. Getting exception in converting Object to map.

Comment: Then you don't have a `List<Map>`

Answer (score 0):

Java 8: if your map is `Map<String, String>` then

```
quotationList.forEach(item -> item.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
    }));
```

Comment: then it might be that quotationList does not contain a Map

Comment: It contains, because, if I put it to the map and pass it to the frontend , it showing all values

Comment: how can you be so sure, can you try to put this on you code   System.out.println(quotationList.get(0) instanceof Map);

Answer (score 0):

In case list contains element then your code should print the contents of the map.

Here is your code having one map element in the list and it is printing the contents of the map:

List> quotationList= new ArrayList>();

```
    Map<String, Object> map= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");

    quotationList.add(map);

    for (int i = 0; i < quotationList.size(); i++) {
        Map myMap = (Map) quotationList.get(i);
        System.out.println("Data For Map" + i);
        for (Entry<String, Object> entrySet : ((Map<String, Object>) myMap).entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + entrySet.getKey() + " , Value = " + entrySet.getValue());
        }
    }
```

It will produce the output as:

Data For Map0
Key = key1 , Value = value1

Comment: It's working fine in most of the cases, but not in case, As, it contains an instance of a model.